# Netbeans and sorting lines, any way to do it?

Tags: netbeans

There's an old plug-in for NetBeans called Line Tools that enabled sorting lines alphanumerically. I can't get it to work though, and I don't expect to given how old it is.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3857/line-tools

The author on that page claims the features are now present in the current NetBeans, but I think he's referring to the actions "Move/Copy Selection/Line Up Down" and not the line sorting.

Is there a built-in way or any plug-ins to sort lines (by selection) in NetBeans? I've looked at NetBeans key maps and couldn't find anything of the.. sort.

Answer (score 5):

I found [Sort Line Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/45925/line-tools-nb-7-x-compatible) NetBeans plugin. Looks like what you (and I) need.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Eclipse sorted imports out of the box. NetBeans could do that without an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/6896/japplis-toolbox. There is also a function to sort lines and even more features.